# switch statement for header redirection

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['ssl'])) {
    switch ($_GET['ssl']) {
        case 1:
            {
            header("Location: https://site.com");
            exit;
            }
        default:
            {
            header("Location: http://site.com");
            exit;
            }
    }
}
```

Should I be using `exit;` because I'm using header? Or should I use `break` like the `switch` requires?

Comment: yeah for what? `exit` or `break`?

Comment: My apologies for a flippant answer previously. Break's are typically used in the context of a switch or loop statement; exit/die function calls usually indicate a short-circuiting of the current code at that point in the code. My preference is to first indicate that ssl (https) is preferred/required (using header()), so that the following session/activity follows this protocol, instead of constant checking for ssl for every request. This means early detection and redirection, before anything else has been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I still feel bad about that whole exchange yesterday, I figured I'd offer an answer and explain some things to do with `break` and `exit()`.

As amosrivera points out, using a break is not required within a `switch` statement; it is also valid within other loop structures.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

> break ends execution of the current
>   for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.

What this means is that for each one of these loop types, it will stop execution of the current loop, but not the execution of the calling script itself. Note also:

> break accepts an optional numeric
>   argument which tells it how many
>   nested enclosing structures are to be
>   broken out of.

The purpose is to stop executing the loop; in a switch, it prevents fall-through. For example:

```
function mySwitch($var) {
    $return = '';

    switch ($var) {
        case 1:
            $return .= 'a';
        case 2:
            $return .= 'b';
            break;
        case 3:
            $return .= 'c';
    }

    return $return;
}

echo mySwitch(1); // outputs 'ab'
echo mySwitch(2); // outputs 'b'
echo mySwitch(3); // outputs 'c'
```

**See live example: http://codepad.org/8EMvYt7V**

`switch` will match the first case then run each case following until it reaches a `break` or `return`.

*Concerning `return`, if called in a function within a loop, it will end the function execution and, possibly confusingly, [`return()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) will also end the current script execution if called in the global scope, but in a different way from `exit()` (for instance, for `include`'d or `require`'d files, it will not affect the main script).*

How [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) (or `die()`) differ from `break` and `return` is that is ends execution of the entire script, not just the current loop (`break`), function (`return`), or script (`return()`).

Now, I happen to agree with coreyward that it's probable you don't need a switch for this; I use a different method under a potentially different scenario:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {
    exit(header("location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"));
}
```

Which could be rewritten to be:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on' && $_GET['ssl']) {
    exit(header("location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"));
}
```

Or you could create a lookup list of actions/pages that require ssl and call that in the redirect:

```
function requireSSL($page) {
    $req = array('login.php','myaccount.php','updateaccount.php');

    return in_array($page, $req);
}

function doSSLRedirect($page) {
    if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on' && requireSSL($page)) {
        exit(header("location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"));
    }
}
```

Then you can call this when you need to enforce a redirect (and you don't need `$_GET['ssl']` in the URL):

```
doSSLRedirect($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This would be more handy if you're using some kind of MVC pattern and were checking for actions in the URL; otherwise, you could just use an `include checkssl.php` at the head of your script.

Since I don't know how you're actually implementing your SSL check, these are just suggestions. Looking at the code you have above, if that were simply plugged in at the top of a page, you might end up with an infinite loop if you inadvertently add the ssl variable back to the redirected URL.

As far as calling `exit()` (or `die()`), you don't have to pair the two, but they typically do occur at the same time or near each other, since any output that follows should not be seen by the user's browser.

For instance, if you separated them, you might create a check for the redirect in case you have other things you want to happen before exit (maybe some logging or something).

For example:

```
$sslredirected = false;
if (isset($_GET['ssl'])) {
    switch ($_GET['ssl']) {
        case 1:
            header("Location: https://site.com");
            $sslredirected = true;
        default:
            header("Location: http://site.com");
            $sslredirected = false;
    }
}

if ($sslredirected === true) {
    $otherstuff = youNeedToDoBeforeRedirection();
    exit;
}
```

However, in this case you could probably just as easily put that in an `include`'d file and just call that in your `switch` and let it do the `exit()` call. There's a number of different ways this could go.

One other note about using `header()`, you need to call it before anything is outputted (including whitespace). See http://codepad.org/nJ4aght4 for an example of what I mean. Note in this case, the header is not sent, so the redirect will not occur.

Hopefully this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean switch requires `break`, and the point is, it doesn't *requires* it, `break` should be used when needed to after a condition, in this case you are already doing that with `exit` the way you have it is fine.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about break, not return. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

the whole code block is pointless in my opinion, you can achieve the exact same results like so:

```
$protocol = empty($_GET['ssl']) ? 'http' : 'https';
header("Location: " . $protocol . "://site.com");
exit;
```

the function `empty` will be true if the value the index is not defined as well as being empty or `0`.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Exit isn't necessary for the location header to do its job; it's only needed if you're using it to avoid outputting the rest of the page. Worth including? Probably. Forgotten? Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @coreyward 1. it was in the code from the OP. That's alone enough to be a reason. 2. To avoid not just output **but further execution at all.** Sure, it's not to help the location header to do its job, it's to prevent the rest of the page from execution. Although it's not required when no code going to be executed, it's good practice to use exit() by default. It costs you nothing but can save a lot of trouble.

Comment: @col. Shrapnel: I understand what `exit` does, and I think you're right that it would make sense to use it. That said, you can still set cookies/session data, log the redirect action, etc. Just because it is common to use it doesn't make it the standard.

Comment: @coreyward calling Location header should be very last action, as no further code execution is guaranteed (unless script being intentionally disconnected from the server using feature like fastcgi_finish_request()).

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Is what you're saying tested? In theory, PHP buffers header output usually, and Apache buffers output too. You should, then, be able to set any headers you want, sleep for 15 seconds, and then set some more headers or finally finish execution and let PHP/Apache pass the headers back to the browser.

Comment: is this really a huge issue :/, we both know there's pros and cons about the exit, die functions but it depends on the application at hand, @Col. Shrapnel is correct in editing my post as the original post was a snippet, therefore we don't know what comes after it, the OP uses exit so he updated by answer to make it more compliant to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use exit at the end if u need :

```
   if (isset($_GET['ssl'])) {
        switch ($_GET['ssl']) {
            case 1:
                {
                header("Location: https://site.com");
                break;
                }
                default:
                {
                  header("Location: http://site.com");

                }
        }
    }
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` isn't really appropriate here — it's making things more complicated, not less.

```
if (isset($_GET['ssl']) {
  header('Location: ' . ($_GET['ssl'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://example.com/');
  exit();
}
```